# Python/Matplotlib - Change subplot background color based on a binary array of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

The code:

```
labels_0 = []
labels_1 = []

for i in range(len(ensemble_ss)):
    if ensemble_ss.iloc[i, ensemble_ss.columns.get_loc('ens_state')] == 'Long':
        labels_0.append(ensemble_ss.iloc[i, ensemble_ss.columns.get_loc('Close')])
        labels_1.append(float('nan'))
    else:
        labels_0.append(float('nan'))
        labels_1.append(ensemble_ss.iloc[i, ensemble_ss.columns.get_loc('Close')])


fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, sharex = True, figsize=(12,6),dpi=500, 
                        gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [3, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33]})

fig.patch.set_facecolor('silver')

axs[0].plot(labels_0, color="black")
axs[0].plot(labels_1, color="red")
axs[0].plot(ensemble_ss['Cum Return'], color="dimgrey",linewidth = 1.5, linestyle = 'solid')
#axs[0].set_yscale('log')
axs[0].margins(x=0)
axs[0].grid(which='both', axis='both', ls='--')

axs[1].plot(ensemble_ss['ens_state'])

axs[2].plot(ensemble_ss['kf_state'])

axs[3].plot(ensemble_ss['hmm_state'])
```

The DataFrame which I'm plotting from (ensemble_ss) takes the following form:

```
    Date          Symbol     Interval   Open    Close     kf_state   hmm_state   ens_state  Cum Return  
0   2013-01-03    SPY         1D       4.983    4.981     Long       Flat        Long       4.981
1   2013-01-04    SPY         1D       4.983    4.986     Long       Long        Flat       4.986
2   2013-01-07    SPY         1D       4.982    4.983     Flat       Long        Long       4.983   
3   2013-01-08    SPY         1D       4.985    4.980     Flat       Long        Flat       4.980
```

The code above plots this:
[image]

Focusing on the subplots. The blue line flicks back and forth along the y-axis between binary states of 'Long' or 'Flat'.

however what I want to display would look (somewhat) like this:
[image]

Excuse the rough paint job, but the idea is that I want **no line**, rather **the background of the subplots change color** (lets say between green and red) along the timeseries with respect to their state being 'Long' or 'Flat'.

Thanks in advance for any help. I have had a good look over the web but cant seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html?highlight=fill_between#matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between) with red on a green background:

```
axs[1].patch.set_facecolor('g')
axs[1].fill_between(ensemble_ss.index, ensemble_ss['ens_state'], color='r')

axs[2].patch.set_facecolor('g')
axs[2].fill_between(ensemble_ss.index, ensemble_ss['kf_state'], color='r')

axs[3].patch.set_facecolor('g')
axs[3].fill_between(ensemble_ss.index, ensemble_ss['hmm_state'], color='r')
```

[image]